# Wine Install - Do I need Mono, Gecko, etc

Tags: wine

I just did a wine Install on Ubuntu 16.04 and got the dialogue "We can install Mono and Gecko but recommend you do it the proper way". I hit the cancel button figuring I'll install them later. Do I need to actually do this and what's the best way?

I use all kinds of legacy Windows apps that aren't available on Linux.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Mono

You need Mono to run certain applications and components.

It is recommended to install the Microsoft core fonts, some applications require it to work properly.

I suggest you to install PlayOnLinux, so you can manage your Wine prefixes easily by installing the components required for each one.

For example, if you want to install Microsoft Office, PlayOnLinux already has a script which automatically installs the required complements and packages.

You can install mono by using:

`sudo apt install mono-complete`

or (for Ubuntu versions prior to 16.04)

`sudo apt-get install mono-complete`

#### Gecko

For Gecko, check https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko

Comment: Can I install gecko by running `sudo apt install wine-gecko2.21`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Also check this: [Wine-Gecko](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wine-gecko)

Answer (score 1):

To ignore Mono and Gecko popup, you can export the following variable before running your app:

```
export WINEDLLOVERRIDES="mscoree,mshtml="
```

If you do that, rendering of HTML is going to be disabled in some apps.

See: [How to disable Gecko package popup for Wine?](https://superuser.com/q/948508/87805)

---

Alternatively install [Gecko](http://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) by: `sudo apt-get install wine-gecko\*`.

And .NET library by via `winetricks`:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
winetricks dotnet45
```

<sup>See: [Why is Wine not seeing that I have mono 3 installed?](https://superuser.com/q/739240/87805)</sup>

Comment: The suggested alternative Gecko command, entered exactly as stated, now produces "Unable to locate package wine-gecko*"

Answer (score 1):

Other answers were not working for me on 18.04 LTS with `winehq-stable` package. I needed `.NET` framework packages to run a certain application, so I did not need `Mono` in particular, just something that would run `C#` programs.

The workaround I found was to recreate wine32 and wine64 prefixes and install `.NET` on those with the automatic prompt of `winetricks`.

```bsh
    # Create dir for 32 bit prefix
    mkdir ~/.wine32
    # destroy default configuration (64 bit prefix)
    rm -rf ~/.wine 

    # Initial setup (create prefixes)
    WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
    WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" WINEARCH=win64 wine64 wineboot

    # To install dotnet35 on 32-bit prefix
    WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 winetricks dotnet35
```

Comment: I get the error `005c:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed` after following your steps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The answer now specifies that I needed `.NET` and not exactly `Mono`. I did knew that the latter is a free implementation of the first, but I do not know of any Windows application that requires `Mono` specifically and not `.NET`, so can't help you without any more details. In general I believe if you installed `.NET` you should not have any particular problem (apart from common wine bugs in running applications), which I can't help you with since I am not a Wine developer.