# Installing wine in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, wine

I am unable to install Wine in **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** by using terminal as dictated by many youtubers.
please solve my problem beause I have to use windows application on my laptop.

[image: Commands and errors.]

Comment: Either post the commands you used to install it along with the errors it produced (not some vague paraphasing of what you think it says) or solve your own problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post and copy and paste the terminal output rather than linking an image if at all possible. You might benefit from reviewing https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You've got cosmic and bionic repos all mixed up in your sources.list

Comment: Close voters complete answer below.

Answer (score 4):

1. Correct your `sources.list` as suggested [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115454/installing-wine-in-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts#comment1843419_1115454)
2. Backup your existing list (not because it's useful but because it's a best practice)

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
3. Install a correct `sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
4. Add the universe repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   ```
5. Install wine for your architecture:

   **for 32-bit:**

   ```
   sudo apt install wine32
   ```

**OR for 64-bit**

```
    sudo apt install wine64
```

6. If you are running a GUI you might wish to open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> and check that you have all your desired repositories enabled there. I usually check everything on the Ubuntu Software tab and officially supported non-free drivers as well as important security and recommended updates on the Other Software tab.

**Note:** 
Be aware that there are still some [multiarch dependancy issues](https://wiki.winehq.org/Multiarch)

**Personally I'm still running wine on 16.04** as while you can [install mono](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800557/wine-install-do-i-need-mono-gecko-etc) under 18.04 with `sudo apt install mono-complete` some programs I use require gecko and there's currently [no gecko package available for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=wine-gecko)

**Sources:**

[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wine&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all

[How do I restore the sources.list file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49572/how-do-i-restore-the-sources-list-file)

Comment: An edit and an upvote and a vote to leave open.  **;-)**

Comment: This is a good answer; for some reason this seems to be an increasingly frequent problem with new installers who then go off to install wine and mess up their systems.  I'll be sure to refer to this one in the future.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you. It seems they often get into trouble trying to follow instructions from old youtube videos.