# Multiple repository errors when I try any APT command after trying to install signal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, software-installation, signal

I am currently using 18.04.

I wanted to install signal for desktop and I got this code from the site to install on Debian:

```
curl -s https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop
```

Since doing that I can't use APT; whatever I do I get the same error:

```
E: The "sudo" type is unknown in line 2 of the source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The source list could not be read.
Go to the configuration of the repositories to fix the problem.
E: _cache-> open () failed, please report.
```

I've tried to find solutions online but they want me to use the `sources.list` and I am not aware of how to navigate there.

My question has been closed as a duplicate but I can't get to grips with the `sources.list`; it's empty and I don't know how to manipulate it.

I cannot install or do anything because everything I want to do is stopped by the error:

```
Ignoring the file "some-ppa.list.save.1" in the directory "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" because it has an incorrect file extension.
Ignoring the file "some-ppa.list.save.1" in the directory " /etc/apt/sources.list.d/" because it has the incorrect extension. 
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/baitsart/voice-commands/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
Updating from such a repository can not be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
See apt-secure (8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/grasch-simon- listens / simon / ubuntu bionic Release 'does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! try completing steps 1 through 3 [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116525/225694)